# Question on a technical lemma: Operator with bounded inverse

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, proof-explanation, spectral-theory

I'm studying about Hilbert spaces this semester and now we're talking about "Resolvent and Spectrum". Here is a Lemma:

[image]

[image]

I understand the whole proof except for the part : ***"$\;T^{n+1} \to 0\;$ in the operator norm".* Why does this hold?**

I'm sure I'm missing something here but I can't figure out what. Any help would be valuable. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: $T^n\to0$ in operator norm, means $\|T^n\|\to0$. Note that $\|T^n\|\le\|T\|^n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Well it was that simple! Thanks a lot!!